# Vertical Seekbar popup at thumb. Popup misplace

Tags: android, popup, android-seekbar, android-vertical-seekbar

I am working on a app where I am using both Horizontal and Vertical seekbar with showing popup at thumb location.

1. For horizontal seekbar both the things are fine.
2. But when we rotate seekbar by -90/270 degree, then the popup is not    showing on proper location(above the thumb)
3. The problem is we try to get bound of Seekbar thumb for vertical position but i am getting bound of horizontal position.

Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     Try this vertical seekbar. As you see in **setProgress(int progress)** method thumb position will update, automatically. Good
>  luck
> ```

```
import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;

    public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

        public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
        }

        @Override
        protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
            setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
            c.rotate(-90);
            c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

            super.onDraw(c);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (!isEnabled()) {
                return false;
            }

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
                    onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL :
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void setProgress(int progress) {
            super.setProgress(progress);
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
        }
    }
```